# File permission problem updating a .swift file on macOS from Windows 10 on same LAN

Tags: macos, xcode, permission, unix

1. On MacOS 13.2.1 in my work folder I execute: `sudo chmod -R a=rwx *`
2. Finder > file's Get Info > Permissions become:

```
Name "myMacAccount" Privilege "read & write)  
Name staff    Privilege is read & write  
Name everyone   Privilege is read & write.
```

3. On Windows I mount macOS work folder onto D:
4. A text editor on Windows opens file on D: (ie. macOS), changes it and saves it.
5. On macOS, file's permission becomes:

```
Name "myMacAccount" Privilege "read & write  
Name everyone   Privilege "No access"
```

Now Xcode can no longer read the .swift file, until I do the `chmod` again.

What could be causing the issue?

Comment: How do you mount the macOS folder on Windows? Which filesystem format is used on the macOS partition?

Comment: And (also) by "how" what username and password are you using to log in to Windows? The same as you use on the Mac? And are you using a fully qualified login? EG MACNAME\MACUSERNAME and MacPassword?

Comment: What format is the drive? Have you considered just disabling perms on it?